# Mocking CountDownTimer and Handler

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I'm using **Mockito** and **PowerMockito** to write my Unit Test on Android.

I've managed to work with almost all by back stuff, but I'm stuck with the [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

I'm able to mock a subclass of `CountDownTimer`, but I'm not able to mock it's **final method** like [`cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel()), so each time the `cancel()` method is called, the test runner report a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Method cancel in android.os.CountDownTimer not mocked. See ...`

**Do anyone have a solution for this without using Robolectric?**

Comment: what is your mockito version?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be a problem with your compilation structure or test setup. *It may be helpful for you to post more details about your compilation setup and your test code in your question.*

---

Because you're getting "Method...not mocked", you're clearly already using a mock-friendly test library supplied with Android. Recent versions of the Android SDK include this [mockable Android jar](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support), first included with Android Studio and the Android gradle toolchain; with this, all implementations are mockable, so you shouldn't need Robolectric or even PowerMockito to move forward.

> At runtime, tests will be executed against a modified version of android.jar where all `final` modifiers have been stripped off. This lets you use popular mocking libraries, like Mockito.

However, because javac can compile calls to static and final methods using static dispatch (i.e. not dynamic or virtual), you may find yourself unable to take advantage of this `final`-free library if you compile any intermediate artifacts or libraries against a version of android.jar that *does* contain `final` modifiers. If you have a call to the final method in the bytecode, then your only remaining option is to intercept or rewrite the bytecode as Robolectric and PowerMock do. PowerMock and its PrepareForTest annotation can be tricky to get right, so if you've tried that unsuccessfully, you may want to post your code here for a look.

Of course, you'll still be responsible for ensuring that your system-under-test uses the newly-supplied mocks; PowerMock can intercept calls to constructors, and Robolectric replaces the entire Android class with its own alternative, but with pure mocks you'll need to inject that dependency one way or another.

Answer (score -1):

add this line to module `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    } }
```